# Expand/Collapse Navigation content in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, navigation, site-settings

Hi i have around 40 links which will be coming in the navigation , is there a way to collapse it there so that my LEFT HAND NAVIGATION doesn't gets too long?

Comment: Left-hand navigation in SharePoint is called QUICK LAUNCH, you can do it by using some CSS and jQuery hacks.visit this link https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137381/sp-2013-quick-launch-bar-collapse-expand

Answer (score 3):

The whole set of codes is as follows-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    SetAccordionQuicklaunch();
});

function SetAccordionQuicklaunch() {

    var caretMarkup = "<a href='#' class='accordionControl contracted'>&or;</a>";

    // initialize
    $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.static').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('ul').length) {
            $(this).children('a').after(caretMarkup);
            $(this).children('span').after(caretMarkup); // also finds headers that are not links themselves
            $(this).removeClass('selected').children('ul').hide();
        }
    });

    $('.accordionControl').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('contracted')) {
            $('.accordionControl.expanded').each(function () {  
                ContractQuickLaunchSection($(this));            
            });                                                 
            ExpandQuickLaunchSection($(this));
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
            ContractQuickLaunchSection($(this));
        }
        return false;
    });
}

function ContractQuickLaunchSection(accordionControlLink) {
    accordionControlLink.siblings('ul').slideUp();
    accordionControlLink.removeClass('expanded').addClass('contracted');
    accordionControlLink.html('&or;');
}

function ExpandQuickLaunchSection(accordionControlLink) {
    accordionControlLink.siblings('ul').slideDown();
    accordionControlLink.removeClass('contracted').addClass('expanded');
    accordionControlLink.html('&and;');
}
</script>
<style>
#sideNavBox .root li {
    position: relative;
}

a.accordionControl {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;  /* change to "top: 5px;" to have the caret stay on the main link */
    z-index: 1;
}

a.accordionControl:hover,
a.accordionControl:active,
a.accordionControl:focus,
a.accordionControl:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable the Expand and Collapse(accordion) menu in the Current Navigation.

```
<script>
function expandedSelected()
{
var s = $(“div.noindex ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox>ul.root>li.static>ul.static>li.selected”).parent
var p=s.parent();

p.find(‘ul’).css(“display”,””);
p.find(‘ul’).attr(“data-hide”,1);
}
function hideOtherItems()
{
$(“.ms-core-navigation ul.root ul”).each(function(){
if($(this).attr(“data-hide”)!=1) $(this).hide(“slow”);
});
}

function resetDataHideAttr()
{
$(“.ms-core-navigation ul.root ul”).each(function(){
$(this).attr(“data-hide”,0);
});
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
$(‘.ms-core-navigation ul.root ul’).hide();

$(‘.ms-core-navigation ul.root > li.static > span.menu-item’).hover(
function() { $(this).css(“cursor”, “hand”);},
function() { $(this).css(“cursor”, “default”);});

$(‘.ms-core-navigation ul.root > li.static > span.menu-item’).click(
function() {
var p=$(this).parent();
if($(‘ul’ , p).attr(“data-hide”)==1)
{
$(‘ul’ , p).attr(“data-hide”,0);
$(‘ul’, p).hide(“fast”);
}
else
{
resetDataHideAttr();
$(‘ul’ , p).attr(“data-hide”,1);
$(‘ul’, p).show(“fast”);
hideOtherItems();
}
});

expandedSelected();

});</script>
<style>
.ms-core-navigation ul.root li.static
{
padding-bottom:1px;
}
.s4-specialNavLinkList
{
display:none;
}
.ms-core-navigation ul.root li.static ul.static li.static.selected
{
padding-top:1px;
}

.ms-core-navigation ul.root > li > .menu-item, .ms-core-navigationheader, .ms-core-navigationheader:visited
{
background: #4599c3;
color: #ffffff;
}</Style>
```

Comment: Better add a source/link to the code. As for now the quotes are bad formatted. (“ and ” instead of ").

Comment: Great! But do i need to pass any reference js files, i just implemented , its only coloring up the headings, functionality is not working. @Hardik

Comment: You might need to add  **jQuery UI 1.10** or  **jQuery UI 1.9**

Answer (score 0):

Yo can setup menu level to 1 (StaticDisplayLevels attribute and the MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels attribute), hiding the child links:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms466994(v=office.14)