# How can I enable the Expand and Collapse(accordion) menu in the Current Navigation for a Classic Experience SharePoint Site (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to enable the Expanding and Collapsing of the menu in the Current Navigation for a Classic Experience SharePoint Site.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: similar question https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214927/expand-collapse-navigation-content-in-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you can enable the Expanding and Collapsing in the SharePoint Navigation using code. Below articles are about using code to Expand/Collapse for the Quick Launch in SharePoint, which may be helpful to you.

https://sympmarc.com/2015/05/27/simple-expandcollapse-for-the-quick-launch-in-sharepoint-2013-or-sharepoint-online/

https://splearnings.wordpress.com/2015/03/03/expand-collapse-sharepoint-left-menu-navigation-using-javascript/

You can add the script into a single page to make it work in one page, or you can add it into the master page if you’d like it to work on all pages in the Site Collection.